# Можно как нибудь получить разом local storage всех открытых сессий?

Tags: cookie, сессия, localstorage, puppeteer

Я сохраняю local storage по завершению работы пупитиром

```
async function saveLocalStorage() {
    console.log('saving Local Storage...');
    const localStorageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let json = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            const key = localStorage.key(i);
            json[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
        }
        return json;
    });
    //await fs.writeFileSync('./localStorage.json', JSON.stringify(localStorageData, null, 2));
    console.log('saved Local Storage');
    return localStorageData;
}
```

так сохраняются только те ключи, которые принадлежат открытой вкадке (ну да, логично)

Есть ли какой-то способ получить все, абсолютно всё? Вот как getAllCoockies

Answer (score 0):

Пока что я решаю этот вопрос с помощью поочередного закрытия вкладок, попутно собирая local storage